# ERROR: Docker version 1.12.6 not supported, please upgrade to at least 17.03.1, or recommended 17.06.2

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, docker

I just tried to rebuild a docker app (discourse forum), and got the following error: `ERROR: Docker version 1.12.6 not supported, please upgrade to at least 17.03.1, or recommended 17.06.2`.

Now, as far as I knew, I installed docker within the last year. But this makes it seem like I'm lightyears behind, looking at the version difference.

I've googled around on how to upgrade docker from this version but find very confusing information. (Not helpful that docker has multiple versions (incantations) either)

Would anyone be able to help me shed light on how I properly upgrade and/or could also give me some tips on identifying my particular version installed?

`which docker` returns `/usr/bin/docker`. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

I am not sure if this is a generic docker error, or an app-specific one. In which case, the error may be misleading. Just a heads-up.

Comment: Have you got the `docker` package installed, or `docker-engine`? Are they versioned differently?

Comment: @SamWilson I'm not entirely sure. Any way to distinguish between the two?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* I solved this problem when I had it by uninstalling `docker-engine` and `docker` (but not removing the apt sources) and reinstalling `docker` by following [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/).

[Here](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T179649) are some notes about how we upgraded Docker (also for Discourse). Unfortunately, I didn't write down the specifics of the Docker upgrade.